# Sticky navbar no longer working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My client wants me to use a template. this one: http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0TK5663

I've been working quite a while in it and I had little to no problems.

However, all of the sudden the sticky navbar is not working anymore. I can't find the answer anywhere and its getting pretty frustrating.

Here is the website: http://soldaforte.com.

just adding position: fixed doesnt do the job, it has to be as in the link I've shown.

Thanks

Edit: I DID add some of my code to directly customize the sticky navbar, and it WORKED, however when I added the flexslider plugin it stopped working.

Comment: Getting error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null on main.js line 48' but js code is minified. Any chance you have the source files for main.js?

Comment: Then the flexi slider might be throwing this error which blocks the js in charge of the sticky navbar from working. Fix the issue with the flexislider and the navbar should work again.

Comment: here is main.js not minified http://codeshare.io/qcrBe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I know what might be happening. I just noticed that main.js is a google maps file, my guess is that the default template is using google maps but you don't have one so it is trying to create a map but it cant. Specifically inside a element with id #gmap

In codigo.js remove this

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -117.243685),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'),
        mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

If you are not using maps then also remove the script tags for those libraries in your html. Otherwise, if you are going to use a map, define the #gmap container and put the code back. Let us know if it works

**Update**

ok it is missing the 'scrolled' class which seems you already knew that based on the scroll listener on the html file. Comparing it to the original theme, the wisdom.js file is missing. In this file the waypoints plugin is set up to handle the sticky nav with this code

```
//Header Animations
var pageHeader = $(".page-header");
var pageSlider = $(".page-slider");
var pageAboutUS = $(".about-us");

pageSlider.waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction == "up") {
        pageHeader.removeClass("scrolled");
    }
    else {
        pageHeader.addClass("scrolled");

    }
}, { offset: -10 });
pageSlider.waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction == "up") {
        pageHeader.removeClass("transition");
    }
    else {
        pageHeader.addClass("transition");

    }
}, { offset: -400 });
pageAboutUS.waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction == "up") {
        pageHeader.removeClass("header-fixed");
    }
    else {
        pageHeader.addClass("header-fixed");

    }
}, { offset: 80 });
pageHeader.waypoint("sticky");
```

I think with this you can get it back working again and fiddle with it to customize its behavior according to your needs. This is if you need animations and transitions between page sections. If you only need a fixed navbar the maybe you'd be better off without the waypoints plugins and set the navbar to fixed via css only.

Comment: That got rid of the error msg in the console, however that doesnt fix it. Also, Removing all trace of flexslider doesnt work either.

Comment: can you publish to soldaforte.com so I can check it out?

Comment: upvote cause that was helpful :), but issue is still there :(, alredy updated

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your css:

```
.stuck.header-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Amazing but I'm just missing out the animation and the new size as in the template, upvote for you c: